# Unable to make an installable WPA with workers and javascript

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-worker, worker

I'm trying to make an installable WPA (Web Progressive App)

I was checking here and there... found out I needed to add a manifest => done

`<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="white">`
`<link rel="manifest" href="/pathtomanifest.webmanifest" />`

my .manifest looks like this

```
{
    "theme_color": "#4a90e2",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/", // -->> also tried with full https://example.com
    "start_url": "/",  // -->> also tried with full https://example.com
    "name": "name",
    "short_name": "shortname",
    "description": "Rss feeds",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/manifests/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any maskable"
        }
        // up to 512x512
    ]
}
```

after, I need to register a worker like this

```
async function workers_load () {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    try { await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/workers.js'); console.log(`stubworker loaded`); } 
    catch (e) { console.log(`SW registration failed`); }
  }
}
```

and load it

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { workers_load(); }, false);
```

my workers.js

```
    const CACHE_NAME = 'offline';
const OFFLINE_URL = '/templates/account_js/workers/stuboffline.html';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) { 
    console.log("stubworker installed", event); 
    event.waitUntil((async () => { const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME); await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, {cache: 'reload'})); })());
    self.skipWaiting();
})

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event){ 
    console.log("stubworker activated", event); 
    event.waitUntil((async () => { if ('navigationPreload' in self.registration) { await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable(); } })());
    self.clients.claim();
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) { 
    console.log("stubworker fetch", event); 
});
```

When I load the page I get in the console I get this

```
worker installed InstallEvent {isTrusted: true, type: "install", target: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, currentTarget: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, eventPhase: 2, …}
worker loaded
workers.js?v=4:2 stubworker activated ExtendableEvent {isTrusted: true, type: "activate", target: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, currentTarget: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

When I go to google Lighthouse for testing

It tells me 2 errors

```
Web app manifest or service worker do not meet the installability requirements 

This origin has one or more service workers, however the page (...) is not in scope.
```

it tells me also this

```
Failure reason
No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest.
```

it seems related to the manifest, but what I'm I missing in my manifest

[image]

What code I'm I missing to make it "installable" ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have to make few modif to make it work

1- register the worker

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ws.js?v=31',{scope: '/' }); 
    console.log("worker registered"); }
}, false);
```

2- *** ABSOLUT MUST ==>> ws.js needs to be in root html folder

3- Manifest

```
 "theme_color": "#4a90e2",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "start_url": "https://www.example.com/",
    "name": "name",
    "short_name": "name",
    "description": "Rss feeds from around the world",
    "categories": ["news","feeds","rss"],
    "dir": "auto",
    "orientation": "any",
```

4- ws.js starting point

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) { });

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event){ });

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) { });
```